# How to convert List<List<List<Int>>> into Bitmap object in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a data class (generated using JSON to Kotlin Data Class plugin) below that is used to parse json data from an object detection server. The server returns the "images" in multidimensional array. I am wondering how can I convert this JSON data in format that can be displayed in my ImageView in Kotlin.

[Data Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHMuQ.png)

[JSON Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lxHo.png)

Your answers will be highly appreciated. Thankss!

Currently, I have this code that transform the images array into a bitmap. However, no image was being displayed in my ImageView.

[Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzmlZ.png)

Comment: Post normal. Post all as text. No images.

Comment: Please paste the text of your code, not an image. Otherwise people have to retype it from scratch before they can make tweaks to show you what to fix. Also, it’s harder to read as an image. The list is three dimensional, but a bitmap is two dimensional. Is the goal to create a list of bitmaps?

Comment: In addition to all the above, please explain **in detail** what the JSON represents. For example, `images` seems to be a bunch of `[7, 7, 7]` triples. What do they represent? What does a value of `7` represent?

Comment: I'm so sorry about the format of the question. I'm new to asking questions in Stackoverflow. My goal is to render the three-dimensional list in my layout ImageView.

Comment: The `images` is the output image returned by my object detection model. It has bounding boxes per object in the image. I'd like to display this returned image in my image view in my layout.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.